# jquery noconflict for email spam protection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running into some conflicts as far as running the jquery noconflict setting on multiple functions, so I decided to isolate the problem by testing the noconflict against one of the functions I'm testing out.

I've tried multiple variations on where I was placing the s$ however none of the configurations seem to work. The only way I can get this work is by leaving the variable as -> var $, and all of the dependent variables to this setting, however I need to find out how I can get this to work using a unique variable?

Perhaps there's an issue with my syntax as well?

```
var s$ = jQuery.noConflict();

s$.fn.emailSpamProtection = function(className) {

return s$(this).find("." + className).each(function() {
var $email = s$(this);
var address = $email.text()
.replace(/\s*\[at\]\s*/, '@')
.replace(/\s*\[dot\]\s*/g, '.');
$email.html('<a href="mailto:' + address + '">'+ address +'</a>');
    });
};
```

Here's the revised script I tried out.

```
jQuery.noConflict();

(function($){
$.fn.emailSpamProtection = function(className) {
 return this.find("." + className).each(function() {
        var $email = this;
        var address = $email.text()
        .replace(/\s*\[at\]\s*/, '@')
        .replace(/\s*\[dot\]\s*/g, '.');
        $email.html('<a href="mailto:' + address + '">'+ address +'</a>');
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

And I placed this into my .html homepage

```
jQuery(function($){

    //Note, you can use $(...) because you are wrapping everything within a jQuery function
    $("body").emailSpamProtection("email");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're using the noConflict attribute correctly.  This is how I would use it:

```
//Establish jQuery noConflict mode.
jQuery.noConflict();

//Define your jQuery plugins/functions
(function($){
$.fn.emailSpamProtection = function(className) {
 return this.find("." + className).each(function() {
        var $email = this;
        var address = $email.text()
        .replace(/\s*\[at\]\s*/, '@')
        .replace(/\s*\[dot\]\s*/g, '.');
        $email.html('<a href="mailto:' + address + '">'+ address +'</a>');
    });
};
})(jQuery);


// Use jQuery with $(...)
jQuery(function($){

    //Note, you can use $(...) because you are wrapping everything within a jQuery function
    $('#myElement').emailSpamProtection();

});
```

Comment: Ok, I gave that a try, however no luck getting the email links to display. Here is what I placed in the jquery function of my homepage. I've updated my original question with the revised script.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. After doing some trial and error, I was able to resolve the issue by flipping the variable to `$j` as opposed to `j$`. Here's my final result.

```
//JQuery Section

var $j=jQuery.noConflict();

  //Hiding other scripts that were included in this application.js file//


//email spam protection - Example Markup: <span class="email">name[at]domain[dot]com</span>
$j.fn.emailSpamProtection = function(className) {

return $j(this).find("." + className).each(function() {
var email = $j(this);
var address = email.text()
.replace(/\s*\[at\]\s*/, '@')
.replace(/\s*\[dot\]\s*/g, '.');
email.html('<a href="mailto:' + address + '">'+ address +'</a>');
    });
};

});

//Script added to the presentation page (html,php,whatever)

<script>
$j(function() {

  $j("body").emailSpamProtection("email"); 

});
</script>
```